# systemd: How to list or edit a masked service unit file definition?

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

Normally one can see what is the definition of a `foo.service` unit file the following ways:

```
systemctl cat foo.service
```

Or, alternatively:

```
systemctl edit --full foo.service
```

In the examples above, you would be able to see the unit file definition, even if you have no actual intention of editing it.

However, say that unit file is masked:

```
systemctl mask foo.service
```

**Question: Is it possible to somehow use `systemd` to see the definition of the unit file even when it is masked?**

The two examples below fail:

```
$ sudo systemctl edit --full foo.service
Cannot edit foo.service: unit is masked.
$ sudo systemctl cat foo.service
# Unit foo.service is masked.
```

Note: Opening the original location of the file with your `$EDITOR` doesn't count. **I am NOT looking for an answer like `$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/foo.service`.** It defeats the whole point of the `systemctl cat` or `systemctl edit` abstractions. I am looking for something like `$ systemctl cat --masked foo`, using a systemd-specific tool to read the preset unit file definition.

This information probably doesn't matter, but in case it does: I am using `systemd 248.3` on Arch Linux.